# Hudson-notification about failed job problem

Tags: email, hudson

In Hudson CI I have configured some jobs to notify commiters who broke the latest build.

My problem: 
 - I have jobs: A, B, C
 - I have users: U1, U2, U3

For instance U1 commit something up to project A, U2 to C and U3 to A.
And let's say, U3 made a mistake and his/her change won't compile.
Currently because U1, U2 and U3 uploaded their changes in t

U1, U2 and U3 commited their changes in a given time frame, so in the last 5 minutes, so these changes will be handled (?) in Hudson inside one big Change.
Currently Hudson handles these uploads in one transaction.
So when any of this commits triggers a failed job -> every commiter will get a mail
U2 also, although his upload was ok, and he didn't touched the problematic P1 project.

My question: how can I configure Hudson to send email notification only to U3 or to U3 + U1 but not to U2. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on ff they are committing to the same repository (say the same project in SVN) and if the changes are picked up from there.

If u1, u2 and u3 commit to a svn project xyz, and the job A or B or C you are saying is built from this project in svn, and the job fails, Hudson sends emails to all the users who checked in to this repository where the job is built from, i.e., diff from the last run of the job and changes that got on top of them.

So, even if say as in this example U2's changes are not causing the failure, Hudson has no idea about this. It just sends emails to "all" the committers.. Unfortunately, we see the same issue when picking up externals or other library projects, but thats the way to go about it----if there is a commit, it might be relate to failure, so send notification..

we can't avoid it :-) .. (unless in future there is some intelligent way to tell if a change caused a failure or not).. hope this helps

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply! But unfortunately P1, P2 and P3 are really separated maven based projects. Theoretically they have no common part, only at the dependency level. (but that's another issue, i would think) So all projects uses the same repo, but there is no common part. At Hudson level J1 job builds P1 J2 builds P2 and J3 P3. (so no common xyz project)

I would think this is not a big issue to determine which user caused the problem in P1, if you have real separated projects/jobs.

Comment: oh cool,, then you won't face the issue of notification being sent to U2.. Hudson's failure trigger sends notification only to users whose "checkins" are in the change log for the specific project.

Comment: No. Unfortunately U1 U2 and U3 also has got notification about project P1 failure because these users made commit almost in the same time (I think).

Anyway what is the main rule behind the break up of Changes?
I mean when I check one job's Changes link, I can see for example these kind of things:

Changes
#13 (2011.02.16. 12:33:29)
12313 comment 31
12312 comment 22
12311 comment 21

#12 (2011.02.16. 09:33:29)
12213 comment 13

#11 (2011.02.14. 09:33:29)
10213 comment 3

But at our side these commits related to different components:
12313 comment 31
12312 comment 22
12311 comment 21

Answer (score 0):

I think Hudson (Jenkins) cares about changes related to a job's workspace. So if you can get job A to fetch code only from project A (narrow down the SCM link), commits to project C should not cause notifications when job A fails.

Take a look at the "changes" link on the job A page in Hudson to see if commits to project C are listed.

Comment: It's listed.
Under Job A > Configure > Source Code Management we set Sub-path. So it's narrowed. 
But under Job A > Changes I can see commits which are related to other job/project!

Maybe our Hudson is misconfigured? I don't know, and donno, where can I find a little field/setting what I should thick on, and everything would be really separated... No idea...

Comment: Have you checked the workspace? (Workspace link.)  Sure you're not using a shared, custom workspace?